# Chrome Dev Tools experience section in performance tab not working

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Question regarding - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/05/devtools#cls

I was trying to test this feature using beta 84 and dev 85.

For me - experience section never appeared in performance  tab. What can be the issue?

Comment: Works for me in Chrome Canary. The section is not shown if there's nothing to report.

Comment: There is also "Layout Shift Regions" option in rendering configuration. I activated it to check if Chrome can see those layout shifts at all. And yes - some areas were highlighted, but nothing showed in performance tab (experience section).

Comment: Works for me in Chrome Canary.

Comment: I too am having the same issue. I'm using this page to test: http://output.jsbin.com/zajamil/quiet and no "Experience" section shows up in the Performance tab in either Chrome v84 or Chrome Canary v86

Answer (score 5):

Today I had the same issue in Chrome on MacOS. After enabling "Layout Shift Regions" in "more tools" "rendering" and then doing a profiling in performance tab, the experience session appeared below the timings section, but only if relevant layout shift events exist.